# Group multiple files into batches in a optimal way

Tags: algorithm

I need to group a list of binary files into 4 batches. I don't want to split the individual binary files, just group them in such a way that the total file size for each batch is almost same. Eg., If I have 6 files with sizes 10,20,30,40,50,60 MBs. I would like the group them like 60 in batch 1, 50 in batch 2, 50(40+10) in batch 3, 50(30+20) in batch 4.
Is there an algorithm to achieve optimal grouping in most scenarios. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned already, it's bin packing. Typically one wants to pack the bins as well as possible, and use fewer bins, but it sounds like you always have exactly four and want them to be as evenly-packed as possible.

If you always have the whole list of files available for sorting, I think the "descending worst-fit" method will work:

```
1. sort the list of files
2. for each file in the sorted list:
3.     pack it in the bin which is currently least-packed
```

If you had many bins I'd suggest keeping them in a heap, but given that there's only 4 it's quick enough to go through them all and continually update a reference to the least-packed.

This is a good rundown of the typical packing strategies: http://www.cs.arizona.edu/icon/oddsends/bpack/bpack.htm

Answer (score 1):

It remembers me the bin pack problem -> http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bin_packing_problem
The size in your case is the dimension of the biggest file, since you don't want to split them.